# PHP displays \r\n characters when echoed in Textarea

Tags: php

My Data is reading data saved from the database (Text).

My problem is that it also has these characters: \r\n

How can I stop those characters showing?

Comment: Improve your question posting some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the nl2br function with the database text in parameter before putting it in your textarea.

The \r\n characters are ASCII "invisible" characters, coding the [carriage return and the line feed](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_Return_Line_Feed), or, if you prefer, the fact that there is a new line.

You need to change those ASCII code into HTML code, which is exactly what [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php) does.

Answer (score 3):

Did you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when pulling data from the DB? If so, stop that. You just have to use this when inserting data into the DB.

Another way: Use `nl2br()` before echoing.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you want to store your data into database, you have to use `nl2br()` function in PHP to convert the **\r\n** to `<br/>` tag before saving data.

So, everywhere you want show that value in your project, everything will be fine.

Comment: It is much more important to use mysql_real_escape_string when writing to DB (for securitiy reasons). nl2br() is almost just for markup and beauty.

Comment: Questioner did not ask about database security. The question was just about \r\n

Comment: Aspects of security should be respected always!!